# Limit number of links to show in custom paging

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Now with my code i see all pages, but i want to limit the number of links.
If i have 10 pages, but i want to see only five: 
 **1** 2 3 4 5,
 5 6 **7** 8 9.
How can i do that? This is [plunk demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/wWnelbNbHfyeOZo11E4o?p=preview) on part of my code

This is my controller:

```
var booksController = function () {
function all(context) {
  var size = 2,
        page = +context.params['page'] || 0;
    templates.get('books')
        .then(function (template) {
            var booksRef = firebase.database().ref('books');
            booksRef = booksRef.orderByChild('timestamp');
            booksRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
                this.data = [];

                snapshot.forEach(function (child) {
                    this.data.push(child.val());
                }.bind(this));

                var pagesLen = Math.ceil(data.length / size),
                pages = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < pagesLen; i+= 1) {
                pages.push({
                    page: i,
                    displayPage: i + 1
                });
            }
            data = data.slice(page * size, (page + 1) * size);

                context.$element().html(template({
                    books: data,
                    pages: pages
                }));
            });
        });
}
 return { all: all };
}();
```

And my hadlebars template:

```
<section id="primary-content">
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1 class="above">Books: </h1>
                {{#each books}} 
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        {{/each}}
    <div id="medium">
       </div> {{!--end medium--}}
        <ul class="pagination">
    {{#pages}}
        <li>
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="#/books/{{page}}">{{displayPage}}</a>
        </li>
    {{/pages}}
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: make sure that pagesLen is not greater  than five in ``for (var i = 0; i < pagesLen; i+= 1) {
                pages.push({
                    page: i,
                    displayPage: i + 1
                });
            }  ``

Comment: Can you show me with code?

Comment: I think i need two variables - startPage and endPage, but i am not sure how to do it...

Comment: do you want that hardcoded or a variable?

Comment: Show me what you think about is the better option

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you want to acheive

Comment: For now i have only 4 pages, but i will have more. So i don`t  want to have for example 50 pages and 50 <li> will load for every page. I want to limit links that are shown. If currentPage = 1, pagesLen = 50, linksToShow = 5 => 1 2 3 4 5.    If currentPage = 5, pagesLen = 50, linksToShow = 10 =>  5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14.

Comment: ok, one way would be to be to set i based on the current page, and pagesLen to whichever is less of the totalpages-currentPage and your limit.

Comment: How this should look like?